# Ubuntu 14.04 install using Wubi on Windows 8.1 no preinstall

Tags: 14.04, wubi, windows-8

I have Dell laptop on which I have installed Windows 8.1. It is not pre-installed setup but I have later upgraded my windows to 8.1 version from 7->8->8.1.

I was able to install Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi (because I don't have that secure boot or UEFI stuff) and it is working great.

But now I want to install Ubuntu 14.04, however upon trying to install, it did not show me the menu and directly went to this page (window).

[image]

How can I force it to install with 14.04 because I know it works perfectly atleast on my computer.

Comment: Is there wubi.exe file in same folder (neat to) with iso file?

Comment: Yeah. Actually, I got the fix. We need to copy wubi.exe to disk and then run it. It works now and provides option of installing the ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score -1):

You must be trying to install it from disk image after mounting it on Drive G or H or whatever..
YOu have to extract it in to a folder and then have to go for the installation.

Comment: This is really vague.